# What is the regex to match the text in string which is changes dynamically?

Tags: regex, groovy

I am trying to extract XSRF Token from the response of a request using Groovy Script. What is the regex to match the XSRF-TOKEN value (i.e after = )

`Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=122149d5-8fb1-4059-90cb-ee34f39e7259;Path=/;Domain=10.179.196.111`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex

```
(?<=XSRF-TOKEN=)[a-z0-9\-]+
```

In above regex,`(?<=XSRF-TOKEN=)` means find value starts with `XSRF-TOKEN=` but not include it,`[a-z0-9\-]+` is used to find the value(do not consider uppercase according to your example data)

For your example,the output is

```
122149d5-8fb1-4059-90cb-ee34f39e7259
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regexp:

```
XSRF-TOKEN=([^;]+);
```

which means "capture any one or more symbols, which is not semicolon until the first semicolon".

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive lookbehind `(?<=` and match not a semicolon `[^;]+` one or more times:

[`(?<=XSRF-TOKEN=)[^;]+`](https://regex101.com/r/HxNB4T/1)